# How can I simplify my MVC3 routing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following routes. I think I could simplify them but I am not sure how. Can someone give me some advice on this? What's the reason for id = ... in these routes. If I don't have any id parameters in my methods then is this doing anything?

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_test",
    "Admin/Tests",
    new { controller = "Contents", action = "Tests", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_menus",
    "Admin/Menus",
    new { controller = "Contents", action = "Menus", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_notes",
    "Admin/Pages",
    new { controller = "Contents", action = "Pages", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_cores",
    "Admin/Cores",
    new { controller = "Cores", action = "Cores", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_default3",
    "Admin/References",
    new { controller = "References", action = "References", id =     UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_Contents",
    "Admin/{action}",
    new { controller = "Contents" },
    new { action = "^tests|menus|pages$" }
);

context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_Default",
    "Admin/{controller}",
    new { action = "Index" }
);
```

and then use a little more RESTful action naming conventions on your `Cores` and `References` controllers and use `Index` as default action instead of `Cores` and `References`.

But in the second route definition you probably also want to allow the possibility of the user to specify a different action in the url:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_Default",
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}",
    new { action = "Index" }
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had no idea it was possible to combine with |

Comment: Yes, it is possible. This part of the route definition is called route constraint: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs. You could use one of the built-in route constraints (Regex, HTTP verb) or write a completely custom constraint.

Comment: The first route that matches the url is picked up and routes to the correct action and controller. So www.yoursite.com/ will match the first route and take you to Contents/Tests